# Use an online image in MUI Avatar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use Material UI's [Avatar](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-avatar/) with images outside the website.

```
<Avatar
   src={'http://localhost:3030/images/a/1651325908227-Capture.PNG'}
/>
```

If I try using an online source(not my local server) it seems ok:

```
<Avatar
   src={'https://mui.com/static/images/cards/basement-beside-myself.jpeg'}
/>
```

Other images on the website load correctly from the same backend.

Comment: Providing there's no CORS rules on the target server preventing this, **yes it is possible**. (and of course the target needs to be accessible by the client, so your example of `localhost:3030` won't work in production.)

Comment: Did you try it? Yes, its possible provide the image url is public or accesible from ur page.

Comment: If I replace the url to something like `https://mui.com/static/images/cards/basement-beside-myself.jpeg` it works fine. Also note that if I input `http://localhost:3030/images/a/1651325908227-Capture.PNG` in the browser the image is there.

Comment: Because `http://localhost:3030` is accessible only from your computer.

Comment: But i'm also developing on the same PC. My frontend in on port 3000

Comment: What do you have in `3030`?

Comment: @Lissy93 do I edit CORS in my frontend or backend?

Comment: @kiranvj 3030 has my backend - running feathersjs

Comment: @Youzef Is `http://localhost:3030/images/a/1651325908227-Capture.PNG` accessible from browser else you need to fix that first.

Comment: yes @kiranvj , it is visible, plus images from the backend load in other components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firstly you should check the error on the devtools > network tab, you can see whats happen there(since you dont provide the error image, i cant see the error)

[image]

there are few possible scenario to your problem, either the image does not exist or its blocked by cors

1. if its blocked by cors, you can install cors extension in your browser to allow cors [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en)
2. if the error is 404 it means the image doesnt exist in your localhost:3030 server

Comment: Here is the log for the error  (https://imgtr.ee/images/2023/05/09/lkEoq.png) the image exists but I don't know how to enable the cross-origin with MUI Avatar

Comment: and installing cors extension to allow Cors is only solved for me I guess, but I need a solution to hardcode allow it in code so that every device will work

Comment: i see, so it has problem with the cors, i think you need to configure it on the server, its not reactjs/js fault, its because of your server didnt configure properly

Comment: what language are u using in your server? its easy to configure if you are using nodejs or laravel, you can mention me for the help in server config

Comment: ohh! I see, so it isn't a problem on my client's side? I'm using express node js for the backend. Maybe I need to check it out. Will try it out if this was the issue

Comment: Thank you so much, brother. I tried to add `Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy` to my helmet and it working fine now